# Como apresentar duas colunas em um resultado de um campo lookup?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Estou tentando mostrar não apenas um resultado (`LookupResultField`) para um campo lookup (`FieldKind`, `fkLookup`), mas sim dois, tentei colocar os campos de resultado separados por ponto e virgula, porém não deu certo, o mesmo funciona para o componente DBLookupComboBox, é possível para um campo lookup? quero mostrar num DbGrid.

Comment: Acredito que não seja possível.

Comment: Você pode criar 2 campos fklookup. Um para a descrição 1 e o outro para  a segunda descrição. Se você adicionar o mesmo KeyField para os dois lookups, ao mudar o valor da chave mudará nos 2 lookups. Se você ligar o mesmo dataset nos dois lookups não terá problemas com performance

Comment: vou dar uma olhada, obrigado pela ajuda.